# Count nulls in properties with one LINQ query

Tags: linq, count

Paste into LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Data> list = new List<Data>();
    list.Add(new Data());
    list.Add(new Data{a="a", b="b"});
    list.Add(new Data{a=null, b="b"});

    var queryA = from data in list where data.a == null select data;
    var queryB = from data in list where data.b == null select data;

    var countNulls = new {a = queryA.Count(),b = queryB.Count()};
    countNulls.Dump();
}

class Data
{
    public string a {get;set;}
    public string b {get;set;}
}
```

Instead of using queryA and queryB is it possible to do this in one query?

**Answer**:
All queries below generate exactly same SQL, so it's just a preference of coder what to choose.

```
var countNulls = new 
    { 
        a = queryA.Count(), 
        b = queryB.Count() 
    };

    var countNulls2 = new 
    { 
        a = list.Count(d => d.a == null), 
        b = list.Count(d => d.b == null) 
    };

    var countNulls3 = list.Aggregate(
    new { a = 0, b = 0 },
    (acc, data) => new
    {
        a = acc.a + (data.a == null ? 1 : 0),
        b = acc.b + (data.b == null ? 1 : 0),
    });
```

**Update**: apparently (thanks to Evan Stoev) this task can be done 20x faster on EF's DbSet and it creates one SQL query.

```
var countNulls4 =
    (from data in db.Data
     group data by 1 into g
     select new
     {
         a = g.Sum(data => data.a == null ? 1 : 0),
         b = g.Sum(data => data.b == null ? 1 : 0)
     }).First();
```

Comment: Do you still want the different counts, or are you just looking for one overall count?

Comment: @JonSkeet - good question... because now I understand that I might have misunderstood him..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, you can use [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the result in a single pass over the input sequence:

```
var countNulls = list.Aggregate(
    new { a = 0, b = 0 },
    (acc, data) => new
    {
        a = acc.a + (data.a == null ? 1 : 0),
        b = acc.b + (data.b == null ? 1 : 0),
    });
```

But I'm not sure it would be more efficient compared to 2 separate `Count` calls due to the need of anonymous object allocation on each step.

**UPDATE:** It turns out that you are asking for a single SQL query (so `list` is not actually a `List<Data>` but `DbSet<Data>` I guess). In LINQ to Entities, you can use *group by constant* technique, which combined with replacing `Count(condition)` with `Sum(condition ? 1 : 0)` will produce a nice single SQL query pretty similar to what you would write manually:

```
var countNulls =
    (from data in db.Data
     group data by 1 into g
     select new
     {
         a = g.Sum(data => data.a == null ? 1 : 0),
         b = g.Sum(data => data.b == null ? 1 : 0)
     }).First();
```

Comment: checked this on 30k rows of data and it's not faster or slower because in the end all solutions generate same SQL :)

Comment: Ah, SQL. Why didn't you tell that at the beginning (although I was suspecting something like that). EF? It requires a totally different approach.

Comment: See the update. If you are using what I think, the query will be totally different.

Comment: this solution is around 20x faster than the other ones on may data set, nice, adding to answer

Comment: This _group by constant technique_ seems real nice. Is it your invention? I'm unable to find anything on the web about it. Could you add a reference or explain it in more detail? I think it's crucial to understanding this answer.

Comment: @Abbondanza Thank you, I wish it was my invention, but of course it's not. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinq%5Dgroup+by+constant. It's not hard to be understand though - group by constant basically does not group at all (because it produces single group), but it allows you to use aggregate functions - something you can't do with a regular `select` query.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that takes a predicate:

```
var countNulls = new 
{ 
    a = list.Count(d => d.a == null), 
    b = list.Count(d => d.b == null) 
};
```

Output is:

[image: a = 2, b = 1]

Comment: This is still doing just as much work as the original.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to count nulls for two different object properties regardless if the other one is null. In other words:

```
a=null, b="b"
a="a", b=null
a=null, b=null
```

would return count for 2 and 2.

In that case you can do it this way in one query:

```
var queryAB = from data in list where data.a == null || data.b == null select data;
```